# Can HDD low speed spindle motor be replaced with high speed one?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, sata

Wondering if an HDD low speed spindle motor be replaced with high speed one to increase its read/write speed or if this kind of replacement is ineffective perhaps due to a speed controller inside of the HDD board?

In other words, do all HDD (with different speeds) spindle motors have the same speed?

Comment: A faster spinning platter would also require upgraded read/write electronics to match the speed increase.

Comment: So why [we can interchange HDD platters between different HDDs](https://superuser.com/q/399744/1073810)

Comment: The one person who claimed a successful transplant only replaced the platters, i.e. the recording medium.  The recipient drive still had its original spindle motor, R/W heads & electronics.  That does not contradict what I wrote.  Note that there was no mention of recovery of old data!

Comment: I've disassembled several harddisks to destroy the disks and their data. A harddisk has multiple platters, all fixed in place. Data is not put sequentially on one side of one disk, but (if I understand correctly) spread out over all sides of all disks to speed up writing and reading. Now my question: How can you put the platters back in place so that they are aligned, making it possible to read out old data? (I realise that this is probably not relevant for @C.F.G., but it's relating to the link.)

Comment: @SPRBRN *"<extraneous comments> ... How can you put the platters back ... making it possible to read out old data"* -- For a fixed platter drive that may not be possible.  Drives with removable platters (see https://superuser.com/questions/341497/whats-the-difference-between-a-disk-and-a-drive/341579#341579) would have their R/W heads aligned with a calibration disk (or disk pack).  Disk packs could be shared among drives that were maintained with proper alignment.  But drives with fixed platters don't need alignment once manufactured.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no.

> Although nowadays, you can find hard drives spinning up to 15000 RPM, the most popular drives for desktops and laptops are between 5400 and 7200 RPM. (Revolutions Per Minute).

## What's the difference between 5400 and 7200 RPM hard drives?

> Although 7200 RPM hard drive are without a doubt faster than 5400 RPM drives, 5400 RPM drives offer an average of 100 MB/s read and writes speeds while 7200 RPM drives deliver an average of 120 MB/s read and writes speeds. If you’re trying to decide, consider that both drives are virtually identical with the difference that a 7200 RPM drive is around 20 percent faster than a 5400 RPM drive

[Source](https://pureinfotech.com/difference-5400-7200-rpm-hard-drives/)

Comment: You should use quotation blocks to clearly indicate what content is yours and what belongs to your source. Please read [how to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Came here to say this. Nice answer!

Comment: Low quality answer that should be a comment.  Quoted text is not even relevant to the question or answer, and does not explain why the answer is no.

Comment: @sawdust im pretty sure that the answer would not fit in a comment, nor do I believe it is breaking any community guidelines. The answer  NO is completely relevant here, but hey feel free to answer the question yourself if you think you know better than I do. Im sure the user who posted the question would appreciate it.

Comment: Your seven words and a URL would fit in a comment.  Answers that consist primarily of a link or quoted text are by definition low quality.  You provided no context for the link you quoted.

Comment: @sawdust @ he's asking if all HDD with different speeds have the same speeds. My answer clearly demonstrates the variety of different drive speeds which is something the author does not seem to understand.